# Slow showing / drawing dialogue with ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

My application uses entity framework to pull in a small tiny set of results... It takes about 3 seconds for it to do it? Why might this be?

**Start.cs**

```
...
private void projectToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    NewProject newProjectForm = new NewProject();
    newProjectForm.ShowDialog(); // It seems to take about 3 or 4 seconds to actually get to this :S
}
...
```

**NewProject.cs**

```
public partial class NewProject : Form
{
    private EFProjectTypeRepository projectTypeRepository;

    public NewProject()
    {
        projectTypeRepository = new EFProjectTypeRepository();

        InitializeComponent();
        ListBoxProjectTypes();
    }

    public void ListBoxProjectTypes()
    {    
        DateTime then = DateTime.Now;

        // PreLoadedResources.projectTypes is a preloaded resource which takes split seconds to load.

        ListBoxProjectType.Items.AddRange(PreLoadedResources.projectTypes.Select(item => (object)item.Title).ToArray()); // If I comment this line out, the dialogue is almost instant @ timeTaken  {00:00:00.0010019}

        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeTaken = now.Subtract(then); 
    }
}
```

:

```
timeTaken   {00:00:02.4261369}  System.TimeSpan
```

when I go and show the dialogue a second time, it's instant!

*My listbox shows 1 item so far lol.*

**Notes**:

```
public static class PreLoadedResources
{
    public static IEnumerable<ProjectType> projectTypes;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `ProjectType` references some children that aren't lazy loaded?  If that's the case you could be pulling way more data than you think you are.  Can you show us the `ProjectType` class.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a smoking gun.  The only other thing I can think of is a slow connection to the DB (assuming you're using a DB).

Comment: I think i'm using the (LocalDb)\V11.0. I'm using a database because I thought it'd be easiest to update.

Comment: For now, I'm going to pre-load the resources and shove a load bar in there. No idea why it is so slow <shrugs>

Answer (score 1):

The `ListBox` has to redraw every time you add an item. You can either use Dmitry's method of using `AddRange()`, or you can wrap your loop with `BeginUpdate()`/`EndUpdate()` calls.

```
ListBoxProjectType.BeginUpdate();

foreach( var projectType in projectTypes )
{
    ListBoxProjectType.Items.Add(projectType.Title);
}

ListBoxProjectType.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Good to know about, but unfortunately has not sped up the showing of the dialogue

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is in the data retrieval portion then. You could step through with the debugger to get a better sense of this.

Comment: Okay just did so, and updated my OP, it takes about 2 seconds per line posted by Dmitry. that's where it's slowing up

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace adding individual items to listbox with `AddRange`:

```
public void ListBoxProjectTypes()
{
    IEnumerable<ProjectType> projectTypes = projectTypeRepository.ProjectTypes;
    ListBoxProjectType.Items.AddRange(projectTypes.Select(item => (object)item.Title).ToArray());
}
```

Or simply wrap items adding with `ListBoxProjectType.BeginUpdate` and `ListBoxProjectType.EndUpdate`.

Comment: Good to know about, but unfortunately has not sped up the showing of the dialogue

Comment: It means that problem is somewhere else, in some other part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my IEnumerable to IList made a difference:

```
public static class PreLoadedResources
{
    public static IEnumerable<ProjectType> projectTypes;
}
```

to

```
public static class PreLoadedResources
{
    public static IList<ProjectType> projectTypes;
}
```

then in my loading (which takes a 2 second hit), I just `.ToList` it instead... but now the showdialogue procedure takes split seconds.